# Future variable reference

Tags: datatool, hooks

For a document I am working on I would like to achieve something along the following lines:
In the beginning of the document, a summary of the most important parts mentioned in the document are given. I want to achieve this in a quite automatic manner. Here, a minimal working example is given to visualise better what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DTLnewdb{mwe}

\newcommand\summary[1]{
    \textbf{#1}
    \DTLnewrow{mwe}
    \dtlexpandnewvalue
    \DTLnewdbentry{mwe}{entry}{#1}
    \dtlnoexpandnewvalue
}

\newcommand\printsum{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item filler (preventing error)
    \DTLforeach*{mwe}{\theEntry=entry}{
        \item \theEntry
    }
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Summary}
\printsum

\section{Long text}

\lipsum[1]
\summary{First summary}

\lipsum[2]
\summary{Second summary}

\lipsum[3]
\summary{Third summary}

\section{Wanted effect (but then in the beginning)}
\printsum
\end{document}
```

I have tried searching for some hooks that only display a piece of text after the document has compiled once, but have not been able to find anything that achieves what I want. Besides that, I am not quite sure how to achieve my goal or whether it is possible at all.

Could anybody enlighten me on this issue? Any information on this issue is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the collected summaries in an auxiliary file that you can `\input`. I also implemented an MD5 based check on whether the file differs from what is found at the beginning and warns when a rerun is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the main command for printing and storing the summary
\NewDocumentCommand{\summary}{m}
 {
  \gdeman_summary:n { #1 }
 }
% print the summaries inside itemize
\NewDocumentCommand{\printsum}{}
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \file_if_exist_input:nF { \c_sys_jobname_str.sum } { \item Nothing, so far, rerun LaTeX }
  \end{itemize}
 }
% set up so the summaries are written at end document
\AtEndDocument{ \__gdeman_summary_write: }
% check the file at begin document
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \file_get_mdfive_hash:nN { \c_sys_jobname_str.sum } \l__gdeman_summary_hash_begin_tl
 }
% variables
\seq_new:N \g_gdeman_summary_items_seq
\iow_new:N \g_gdeman_summary_write_iow
\tl_new:N \l__gdeman_summary_hash_begin_tl
\tl_new:N \l__gdeman_summary_hash_end_tl

% main function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gdeman_summary:n
 {
  % print the summary
  \textbf{#1}
  % store it
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gdeman_summary_items_seq { #1 }
 }
% write the summaries in an auxiliary file
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gdeman_summary_write:
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \g_gdeman_summary_write_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str.sum }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_gdeman_summary_items_seq
   {
    \iow_now:Nn \g_gdeman_summary_write_iow { \item ##1 }
   }
  \iow_close:N \g_gdeman_summary_write_iow
  \file_get_mdfive_hash:nN { \c_sys_jobname_str.sum } \l__gdeman_summary_hash_end_tl
  \tl_if_eq:NNF \l__gdeman_summary_hash_begin_tl \l__gdeman_summary_hash_end_tl
   {
    \typeout{Summaries~differ,~rerun~LaTeX}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
\printsum

\section{Long text}

\lipsum[1]
\summary{First summary}

\lipsum[2]
\summary{Second summary}

\lipsum[3]
\summary{Third summary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice piece of code that even works in Overleaf. Thank you very much :)